# Using System en aplicacion C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

estoy iniciando en este mundo de la programacion, un poco de paciencia! al revisar una solucion en ASP.NET encuentro que varios de los archivos no tienen la referencia al namespace "SYSTEM", por lo tanto salen multiples errores. Revise las referencias y aparece System pero con un triangulo amarillo indicando que no esta disponible.
Intento añadir la referencia desde mis archivos locales, pero nada cambia.
Agradezco su ayuda

[image: Icono de system]

Comment: Quiza el motivo es el framework que utilizas

Comment: Como dice en el comentario anterior revisa el numero de version del framework, agrega que aplicacion estas creando y agrega imagen de tus referencias.